# Заменить input на select2

Tags: jquery, php

Есть действующий скрипт.
Для поиска по адресной книге используется форма (input + ajax). Найденное появляется списком ниже `input`.
Если вводится имя - ищет по имени , если номер - ищет по номеру телефона, если телефон не найден, автопереход на форму добавления.

Как заменить `input` на `Select2` сохранив функционал ?

Ниже часть кода выборки и базы.

```
// ...      $q - переданные аяксом данные
$sql = 'SELECT id, nick from tt WHERE nick LIKE "%'.$q.'%" OR tt LIKE "%'.$q.'%" ORDER BY nick ASC LIMIT 10';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$string = '';

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $string .= "<li><a href=#>".$row->nick."</a></li>";
        $string .= "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: наконец то вы нормально сказали, я думаю вам не подойдет select2 :) скорее всего вам нужен плагин типа ui-autocomplete. я только не помню вы jqueryui используете или нет ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в $sql добавьте условие **OR**.

***tt** - это поле с номером телефона?*

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, nick FROM tt WHERE nick LIKE "%'.$q.'%" OR tt LIKE "%'.$q.'%" ORDER BY nick ASC LIMIT 10';
```

Comment: В реальном коде оно конечно есть. Код рабочий. Здесь упрощенный вариант, для понимания как данные выбираются сейчас. 
Select2 придаёт более приятный вид и удобства, только вот не пойму как его "прикрутить".